Link using asp-page renders with empty href after modifying page routes
I created a fresh Razor Pages project in ASP.NET Core and made the following changes to the Index.cshtml and Privacy.cshtml files:
// Index.cshtml
@page "/"
@model IndexModel

// Privacy.cshtml
@page "/privacy"
@model PrivacyModel

// _Layout.cshtml
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/privacy">Privacy</a>
</li>

// Rendered HTML
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/privacy">Privacy</a>

Why do the @page "/" using asp-page="/" render with empty href attributes?

See https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper:

The path to the target Razor page must be provided without the file
extension. The leading / specifies an absolute path. If you omit it,
the framework looks for a page relative to the current one:
<a asp-page="/page">Click</a>
If no valid page name is specified, the tag helper will render the
href attribute with an empty string. If you want to generate a link
to the default page in a folder, you must still include the default
page's file name:
<a asp-page="/folder/index">Folder</a>
This renders as <a href="/folder">Folder</a>
The tag helper will generate an href attribute whose value will be
taken from the route template of the specified page.

So, you must include "Index" as part of the asp-page attribute if the endpoint is represented by a page named "Index":
<a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
By the way, the changes you made to the template pages will have no practical effect because those routes are generated by default anyway.

"/Index" works just fine. Thank you. Other than that I am still confused why @page "/" works but asp-page="/" doesn't :)
About the changes having no practical effect, it's not true. Route /Index is not generated this way so visiting /Index gives 404.

The default routing conventions generate two routes for Index.cshtml: "/" and "/Index". Your first intervention: @page "/" overrode that convention. Try again by removing the route template from the @page directive. Allow the defaults to apply. The asp-page attribute needs a page name. That's why "/" doesn't work. You are missing the name of the page, which is "Index". Don't confuse URLs (routes) with the names of the page files. Have a look at my stuff on routing for more info: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

I took a look and I am still confused, what you are saying is that asp-page needs a page name. In your blog I can see examples where asp-page name takes a route path: <a asp-page="/page">Click</a>

That's right - the name of a page file. In the examples, assume the page is Page.cshtml. The route template generated for that page will be "/page". You can override that by applying an alternative route template to the @page directive.

What do you suggest to remove /Index routes and convert them to / by default so it's more consistent with "modern way" of handling Index?

No need. As I said, the default routing system generates two routes for Index files - "/" and "/Index", in that order. When you pass "/Index" to the asp-page attribute, it selects the first route to render as the href value., i.e "/".
